# Перехват задания на печать в Delphi

Tags: delphi

Подскажите пожалуйста ! На комп в локальной сети подключены несколько принтеров. Необходимо узнать на какой из принтеров из любого приложения (например Word) отправлено задание на печать. И так же, узнать свойства, какие были заданы при печати (количество страниц в документе, качество печати, количество копий, цветность и т.д.). Прога должна стоять на компе, с которого запускается печать (прописана в реестре, например) и перехватывать задание на принтер.

Answer (score 1):

Отслеживание заданий на печать можно осуществить с помощью

1. [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394363%28VS.85%29.aspx), что потребует опроса по времени в цикле заданий на печать,
2. [Print API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff686805%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), что потребует большой работы,
3. возможно, других подходов.

Проще взять готовый софт (с отрытым исходным кодом), например, [Printer Usage Monitoring Application](http://puma.codeplex.com/) и использовать его (или посмотреть, как он сделан).